# php youtube videos search query stopped working on new hosting

Tags: php, youtube, simplexml

I am using following code to retrieve the videos list through youtube video search

```
$query = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?&v=1&key=MY-API-KEY&time=today&q=test&orderby=rating&start-index=1&max-results=24";



  $video_list = simplexml_load_file($query);

 $counts = $video_list->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');
```

The $counts was having the data which I could used. On old hosting it was working fine. Few days back I transferred to new hosting and its stopped working.

The error now I am getting is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object

I have checked with phpinfo() the simplexml is installed on system.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');`?

Comment: not sure I found script having it. It give 404 error when browsing but removing it still script has same error.

Comment: Are you sure you replaced the MY-API-KEY part in the XML link? Also, what happens when you try to visit the URL normally in the web browser?

Comment: yeah the problem I found is on new hosting out going connections are not allowed. Thanks

Comment: @AmalMurali That's how you switch to a namespace using SimpleXML. `http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/` is the URI representing the full "namespace name"; you can use the prefix instead, but that might change later or even vary from document to document.